# avoiding css overlaps while loading div with a url

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop, loading

I am loading url in a div, as div is loaded with url it includes css file which are disturbing my parent page layout. i want to restrict the css to that loading div only, so it may not disturb the other contents on page. I don't want to use iframes as there is some dragdrop work with jquery and it doesn't support a nice way to drag elements from parent page to iframe.
is there any solution?

Comment: Post a code sample so we can see what you have tried. Also, have you considered name spacing your CSS that you are 'loading'?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the jQuery `load` function with something similar to:

```
$('#mydiv').load(myUrl);
```

You can select only the HTML you are interested in from the loaded page by appending a selector to the url (see jQuery docs for [Loading Page Fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)):

```
$('#mydiv').load(myUrl + ' #content');
```

If you require the full page at the url to be rendered using it's own CSS, then the only reliable way of sandboxing this from your own page is using an iframe.

Answer (score -1):

give your parent's elements a specific class/id name, and use that class/id name in your css as the specific selector

Answer (score -1):

Add only div specific css code in that css file.

Comment: that url is loaded randomly means it would be from google.com or cnn.com so i have to restrict it inside div only

Comment: then you have to update your css file classes/id in you stylesheet!